# Identify an early-mid 20th century cast soft metal decorative trinket

Tags: identification, everyday-objects

I'm trying to identify this tiny trinket/bauble. It was found in a crevice inside of a 130-year old dresser. It was very likely dropped there prior to 1960.

It measures 17mm tall by 8mm wide, and is roughly 1mm thick.

It appears to be made of pewter or lead, as it is bend-able without breaking.  (It might not be lead, but bends as if made of lead.)  I cannot tell if it is stamped or cast.  From the detail in the "beading", I would guess stamped, though.

The photo is a view of the front; the back is blank.

It appears that a top part has been broken off, so it might have been a toy bottle of some sort, with the neck now missing.  (Because the metal is bend-able, and because it is so thin, I don't think it can be a broken drawer-pull.)

In response to the questions below:  The dresser was owned by a lower-class worker, specifically a carpenter.  He lived on the outskirts of a town of around 70,000 people in the mid-western United States.  No professional, industrial or political associations known.

I'm wondering if it might have been part of a recognizable child's toy or game, or perhaps a piece of jewelry.

[image: close-up of trinket]

Comment: Probably the broken off end of a drawer pull.

Comment: I thought of that, and mention it in my post.  But the metal bends quite easily, and is not steel or anything a drawer pull would have been made from, in my opinion.  (It is too small to have been a drawer pull from the dresser itself.)

Comment: Where?  *Where?*  What class of people?  Urban?  Rural?  Sporting and industrial associations?  Political associations?

Comment: More detail added to question, per Samuel Russell

Comment: Bowling league?

Comment: Is it cast or stamped?  (I.e. was it made in a mold or pressed from sheet metal?).  What does the back look like?

Comment: Added note about stamped versus cast.  (Can't be sure, but guessing stamped, due to sharpness of detail in the rings of "beads" near the top.)

Comment: Seems too small of an item to be related to a bowling league.  I don't think this relative of mine (the original owner of the dresser and probably the object in question) was a bowler.